# Конструктор запросов

Tags: php, javascript, sql

как выбрать множество данных из 1 таблицы БД для обработки. То есть допустим есть таблица (id, name,lastname) 
и данные( 1,джексон,джексович
          2,валера, валерьевич
          3,андрей,узбеков) 
я допустим хочу взять сразу и 1и2 для обработки, как это сделать ?
Видел, что можно сделать с помошью queryBuilder, но там вроде атрибуты только можна выбрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос, но можно же выбрать через IN(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

Comment: Ну вот допустим у меня есть таблицы "группы" там данные находится название групп(ПФ-312,РУ-64,ПИ-23), и есть таблица "семестр"  там находятся данные о количества семестров (1,23, и т.д. до 12) И я вот хочу с помощью пользовательского интерефейса выбрать группы ПФ-312,РУ-64 с 1 по 3 семестр , после нажимаем кнопку и внизу нам формирует таблицу с данными об оценках по этим 2 -ум группам , за 3-и семестра к примеру.

Comment: Ну IN для того и сделан же, что вы указав через запятую к примеру id (1, 7, 9) можете получить результат 1 запросом

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать.Спасибо.А не подскажете как удобно вывести на страницы данные из таблице для выбора. Я смотрел можно с помощью чекбоксов , но как-то не особо визуально удобно выглядит, может есть другие способы.

Comment: Как то так, если я вас правильно понял: foreach ($array as $item){ echo $item; }

Answer (score 0):

```
$query='SELECT *FROM table_name WHERE id=?';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute([1,2]);
```

Comment: Я наверно не так задал вопрос. У меня вот есть пользовательский , и есть в БД таблица. Я на пользовательском интерефейсе размещаю все данные с помощью селектов, инпутов. Мне надо  сделать так, что бы я выбрал определенные данные по каждому атрибуту или множества данных потом нажал на кнопку и  делался запрос, который я там пропишу.